How do I export this in glb format?
I have made an animation of rolling out mat, and I want to export that to .glb So I can use that in 3d viewer. can you please help? trying since 2 weeks.


You should upload your file (or a simplified version of it), to understand which tools you used for animating and see if and how they can be exported or converted for glb. Lots of Blender tools cannot be directly exported and you'll have to use some workarounds.

Hello and welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "this", "help with", "issue" or "question about", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"

Glb(GLTF) supports only loc/rot/scale keyframes,  skeletal animation (using armatures), and shapekey animation.  I imagine you used some other technique to animate this?
